# Most efficient algorithm to compute a common numerator of a sum of fractions

Tags: algorithm, math

I'm pretty sure that this is the right site for this question, but feel free to move it to some other stackexchange site if it fits there better.

Suppose you have a sum of fractions `a1/d1 + a2/d2 + … + an/dn`.  You want to compute a common numerator and denominator, i.e., rewrite it as `p/q`.  We have the formula

```
p = a1*d2*…*dn + d1*a2*d3*…*dn + … + d1*d2*…d(n-1)*an
q = d1*d2*…*dn.
```

What is the most efficient way to compute these things, in particular, `p`?  You can see that if you compute it naïvely, i.e., using the formula I gave above, you compute a lot of redundant things.  For example, you will compute `d1*d2` `n-1` times.

My first thought was to iteratively compute `d1*d2`, `d1*d2*d3`, … and `dn*d(n-1)`, `dn*d(n-1)*d(n-2)`, … but even this is inefficient, because you will end up computing multiplications in the "middle" twice (e.g., if `n` is large enough, you will compute `d3*d4` twice).

I'm sure this problem could be expressed somehow using maybe some graph theory or combinatorics, but I haven't studied enough of that stuff to have a good feel for it.

And one note: I don't care about cancelation, just the most efficient way to multiply things.

UPDATE:

I should have known that people on stackoverflow would be assuming that these were numbers, but I've been so used to my use case that I forgot to mention this.

We cannot just "divide" out `an` from each term.  The use case here is a symbolic system.  Actually, I am trying to fix a function called `.as_numer_denom()` in the [SymPy computer algebra system](http://www.sympy.org) which presently computes this the naïve way.  See the [corresponding SymPy issue](http://code.google.com/p/sympy/issues/detail?id=2607).

Dividing out things has some problems, which I would like to avoid.  First, there is no guarantee that things will cancel. This is because mathematically, `(a*b)**n != a**n*b**n` in general (if `a` and `b` are positive it holds, but e.g., if `a == b ==-1` and `n == 1/2`, you get `(a*b)**n == 1**(1/2) == 1` but `(-1)**(1/2)*(-1)**(1/2) == I*I == -1`).  So I don't think it's a good idea to assume that dividing by `an` will cancel it in the expression (this may be actually be unfounded, I'd need to check what the code does).

Second, I'd like to also apply a this algorithm to computing the sum of rational functions.  In this case, the terms would automatically be multiplied together into a single polynomial, and "dividing" out each `an` would involve applying the polynomial division algorithm.  You can see in this case, you really do want to compute the most efficient multiplication in the first place.

UPDATE 2:

I think my fears for cancelation of symbolic terms may be unfounded.  SymPy does not cancel things like `x**n*x**(m - n)` automatically, but I think that any exponents that would combine through multiplication would also combine through division, so powers should be canceling.

There is an issue with constants automatically distributing across additions, like:

```
In [13]: 2*(x + y)*z*(S(1)/2)
Out[13]: 
z⋅(2⋅x + 2⋅y)
─────────────
      2
```

But this is first a [bug](http://code.google.com/p/sympy/issues/detail?id=1497) and second could never be a problem (I think) because `1/2` would be split into `1` and `2` by the algorithm that gets the numerator and denominator of each term.

**Nonetheless**, I still want to know how to do this without "dividing out" `di` from each term, so that I can have an efficient algorithm for summing rational functions.

Comment: `a*b` is different from `b*a` in various number systems. But you have to explicitely say that work in such a system or else eveyone assumes that you are talking about integers. For the `(-1)**(1/2)*(-1)**(1/2) == I*I == -1` part, you'll have to do some reading about algebra and multi-valued "functions" before you start saying such things.

Comment: This has nothing to do with commutativity.  But you do inadvertently bring up a good point.  The algorithm will have to work with non-commutative symbols (just dividing out definitely won't work in that case)

Comment: Actually, I don't think this can even make sense for non-commutatives.

Comment: When you say that things don't cancel, do you mean that symbolically, a1*d2*d3*...*dn is not equal to (a1/d1)*d1*d2*d3*...*dn? If that is the case, then you need to describe very explicitly all the rules of your symbolic system. Do you at least have associativity? And, as mentioned before, what about commutativity? What exactly does "division" in this context represent? It's a little unclear to me what your exponentiation example has to do with "cancelling out" in this case of division.

Comment: Also, this makes sense in at least one non-commutative context. Let a_i and d_i be matrices, where a_i/d_i is understood to be a_i multiplied by the inverse of d_i (of course, we need d_i to be invertible). Then, everything still makes sense. This scenario highlights the need to make clear what algebraic rules are in effect because this case makes templatetypedef's answer inapplicable but starblue's remains okay.

Comment: @mhum: So, as I said, I think my fears for cancelation were unfounded.  You can have things like `sqrt(x*y)/sqrt(x)` not reducing to `sqrt(y)` because `sqrt(x*y) != sqrt(x)*sqrt(y)` in general, but I think there's no way that you could get those combined powers in the first place (for the same reason).  Regarding non-commutativity, how would you put `a1*d1**-1 + a2*d2**-1` of a common "denominator"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of adding up `n` quotients in one go I would use pairwise addition of quotients.

- If things cancel out in partial sums then the numbers or polynomials stay smaller, which makes computation faster.
- You avoid the problem of computing the same product multiple times.

You could try to order the additions in a certain way, to make canceling more likely (maybe add quotients with small denominators first?), but I don't know if this would be worthwhile.

If you start from scratch this is simpler to implement, though I'm not sure it fits as a replacement of the problematic routine in SymPy.

**Edit:** To make it more explicit, I propose to compute `a1/d1 + a2/d2 + … + an/dn` as `(…(a1/d1 + a2/d2) + … ) + an/dn`.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding your answer, but I don't think addition is really the problem here, but multiplication, namely the duplicate multiplication.  The final addition is done by `Add(*numers)`, which in SymPy is pretty efficient.  For polynomials, you can do some other things too (I haven't really thought of this much).

Comment: The point is that you do the multiplications piecewise each time you add two quotients.

Comment: I'm sorry.  It's probably because it's late here (I should get some sleep), but I don't understand what you are saying.  Could you give a small example?

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying now.  I'll need to work this out on paper to see if it's really efficient or not.

Comment: I'll wait until I've slept (probably a good idea), but I think you may have found the answer.  Very novel. I would have never thought of it.

Comment: I would probably split the addition "in the middle", rather than piece-meal, but it probably doesn't matter THAT much, just a smidgen more efficient if you intend to ever distribute it (the two halves aren't inherently synchronised, only the combining of them). If you split it serially, later stages are inherently synchronised on teh results of earlier stages.

Comment: Not exactly the same, but this approach is reminiscent of Horner's rule. See: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HornersRule.html  and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner_scheme

Comment: This is just the generic approach for extending a binary operation to `n` operands, nothing special in my view.

Comment: @mhum, yeah, it reminded me of that too, though they are technically different.

Comment: @starblue, as far as I can tell, this does things the most efficiently.  It's rather ironic that doing it this way would (it's quite paradoxical).  But as far as I can tell, this doesn't do any duplicate multiplications, other than those that are unavoidable (like computing `d3*d1` when you already have `d1*d2` and `d1*d2*d3`).

Answer (score 3):

Compute two new arrays:

The first contains partial multiples to the left: `l[0] = 1, l[i] = l[i-1] * d[i]`

The second contains partial multiples to the right: `r[n-1] = 1, r[i] = d[i] * r[i+1]`

In both cases, `1` is the multiplicative identity of whatever ring you are working in.

Then each of your terms on the top, `t[i] = l[i-1] * a[i] * r[i+1]`

This assumes multiplication is associative, but it need not be commutative.

As a first optimization, you don't actually have to create `r` as an array: you can do a first pass to calculate all the `l` values, and accumulate the `r` values during a second (backward) pass to calculate the summands. No need to actually store the `r` values since you use each one once, in order.

In your question you say that this computes `d3*d4` twice, but it doesn't. It does multiply two different values by `d4` (one a right-multiplication and the other a left-multiplication), but that's not exactly a repeated operation. Anyway, the total number of multiplications is about `4*n`, vs. `2*n` multiplications and `n` divisions for the other approach that doesn't work in non-commutative multiplication or non-field rings.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to compute `p` in the above expression, one way to do this would be to multiply together all of the denominators (in O(n), where n is the number of fractions), letting this value be `D`.  Then, iterate across all of the fractions and for each fraction with numerator a<sub>i</sub> and denominator d<sub>i</sub>, compute a<sub>i</sub> * D / d<sub>i</sub>.  This last term is equal to the product of the numerator of the fraction and all of the denominators other than its own.  Each of these terms can be computed in O(1) time (assuming you're using hardware multiplication, otherwise it might take longer), and you can sum them all up in O(n) time.

This gives an O(n)-time algorithm for computing the numerator and denominator of the new fraction.

Comment: Seems too obvious.  Never was really interested in benchmarking, but isn't division a lot more expensive than multiplication?  I thought there might be a reason he specifically asked for multiplication strategies.

Comment: @bdares- I'm not sure about the absolute performance of this code, but based on the OP's question it didn't seem like he had considered it (he seemed to be trying to multiply inward from both sides, which is much less efficient).  Without knowing the relative tradeoff of multiplications vs. divisions, it would be hard to design an algorithm that would run faster.  Do you know that number by any chance?

Comment: This may work for small `n` values. If `n` is big enough, say 1M+, and all fractions have small denominators, it will grow to a huge (but unneeded) `D`.

Comment: @templatetypedef nope, not at all

Comment: OK, I forgot to exclude this option.  I'll add a bit to the OP explaining why.

Comment: So I added an update to the question.  Not what you were thinking, huh? :)  Anyway, I think this would be the best option otherwise, and actually I'm going to take a closer look at the code to see if I actually can just do this in the non-rational function case (when we are just dealing with ordinary expressions that won't automatically combine into each other).

Comment: See my second update to the question.  Your response got me thinking about this more, and made me realize that my initial aversion to division may have been unfounded.  But I still do want to know how to do this the other way.  Anyway, I've upvoted you, but won't mark this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

It was also pointed out to me that you could manually sift out common denominators and combine those trivially without multiplication.